# Есть ли библиотека Python для управления комплектующими компьютера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли такая библиотека для Python, с помощью которой я бы мог управлять комплектующими компьютера, заставить кулер/видеокарту компьютера работать на полную? Скажем, консольное приложение. Ввёл команду `cooler max` и компьютер зашумел. Ввёл `cooler default` и кулер пришёл к изначальной своей скорости.

Comment: py-библиотека для такого только как API может выступать такой язык сценариев, ищите любое решение, и смотрите реализовано ли там вариант для python/cpython/jython?

Comment: Так же моежете написать, если знаете такие библиотеки / api для Java, C, C++